# How does redux keep independent state for the same component of many page when routing?

Tags: redux, react-redux

When I use Redux with react-router, I have the same component 'ticker' on pageA and pageB, when I dispatch action to 'ticker' on pageA and then route to pageB, 'ticker' on pageB is pageA's 'ticker's' state.

How can I split the component state? 
And if has a easy way to set all the state to default state when routing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's a good idea to store component-specific state inside React's component state. In your case, if you want the state for each component to be reinitialized every time it is remounted, then it's better to update the state using React's `setState`.

Redux creator's opinion on this matter: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287#issuecomment-175351978

On the other hand, if you want pageA's component state to be preserved between route transitions, then I'd imagine you'll have to assign some sort of ID to pageA's , and use that to store the corresponding state data in the redux store.